# Запрос к telegram API не удался. Ошибка 404

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Код:

```
import telebot
token = 'token'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
@bot.message_handler(content_tipes=["text"])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Привет":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, чем я могу тебе помочь?")
    elif message.text == "/help":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напиши привет")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши /help")

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

При запуске выдает ошибку:

```
2021-06-26 23:19:57,009 (__init__.py:544 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 404. Description: Not Found"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На будущее - не светите свой токен! Если узнать хоть один `chat_id` юзера, или к примеру даже ваш - можно послать `POST`-запрос, не от вашего имени. Сгенерируйте у `BotFather` новый токен.

А проблема в том, что вы неправильно указали токен. Уберите с двух сторон знак `%`, он там не нужен.

```
import telebot
token = 'token'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
@bot.message_handler(content_tipes=["text"])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "Привет":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, чем я могу тебе помочь?")
    elif message.text == "/help":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напиши привет")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши /help")

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```